# matching columns of datatables

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two excel files that have same columns but with different names.

I have to find the column name from the source, and find the same column name for the target. There names can be different. I have to compare the values to find out the matching column names.

For example one excel sheet may have

```
Order ID   Quantity   Units
---------  -------   --------
1022         7          55
```

The Other one can have

```
Order ID   Qty         Unt
--------   --------   --------
1022         7          55
```

So by comparing the data, I know that Qty and Quantity are same and Unit and Unt.

I using a data adapter and filling two data tables by reading the excel sheets. 
I want to know how match the two columns given that their ID is the same (order id) and by comparing the values by using both the data tables.

```
    string _basePath = @"C:\Users\Dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Excel2\Excel2\";
    string _targetConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _basePath + "Target.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
    string _sourceConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _basePath + "Source.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Target$]", _targetConnStr);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds, "targetTable");
    DataTable _targetDataTable = ds.Tables["targetTable"];

    adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [4028001$]", _sourceConnStr);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds, "sourceTable");
    DataTable _sourceDateTable = ds.Tables["sourceTable"];

        foreach (DataRow row in _targetDataTable.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
        {
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) // Loop over the items.
            {
               Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you meen when says "map two columns"?

Comment: use LINQ and do a join of the two tables on order ID.

Comment: I have to find the column name from the source, and find the same column name for the target. There names can be different. I have to compare the values to find out the matching column names.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that file 1 uses fields a,b,c and that file 2 uses field names x,y,z then you can use field name aliases on your select statement.

For example:

```
SELECT OrderID as "Order ID", Quantity as "Quantity", Units as "Units" FROM [Target$]
```

and

```
SELECT OrderID as "Order ID", Qty as "Quantity", as Unt "Units" FROM [4028001$]
```

then both result sets can be referenced with the same column names ("Order ID", "Quantity", and "Units")

Comment: This is not known to me, I have to pro-grammatically find out the matching columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can use column index that is:
_targetDataTable.Columns[0] with  _sourceDateTable.Columns[0] 
_targetDataTable.Columns[1] with  _sourceDateTable.Columns[1] 1 for second column that is qty or quantity
and so on